# Implementing QuickSort recursively in C#

Tags: c#, quicksort

I started learning algorithms and I am trying to implement Quicksort in C#.
This is my code:

```
class QuickSortDemo
{
    public void Swap(ref int InputA, ref int InputB)
    {
        InputA = InputA + InputB;
        InputB = InputA - InputB;
        InputA = InputA - InputB;
    }

    public int Partition(int[] InputArray, int Low, int High)
    {
        int Pivot = InputArray[Low];
        int LoopVariable1 = Low - 1;
        int LoopVariable2 = High + 1;
        while (true)
        {

            while (InputArray[--LoopVariable2] > Pivot) ;

            while (InputArray[++LoopVariable1] < Pivot) ;


            if (LoopVariable1 < LoopVariable2)
            {
                Swap(ref InputArray[LoopVariable1], ref InputArray[LoopVariable2]);
                for (int LoopVariable = Low; LoopVariable <= High; LoopVariable++)
                {
                    Console.Write(InputArray[LoopVariable] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            }
            else
            {
                for (int LoopVariable = Low; LoopVariable <= High; LoopVariable++)
                {
                    Console.Write(InputArray[LoopVariable] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                return LoopVariable2;
            }
        }
    }

    public void QuickSort(int[] InputArray,int Low, int High)
    {
        if (Low < High)
        {
            int Mid = Partition(InputArray, Low, High);
            QuickSort(InputArray, Low, Mid);
            QuickSort(InputArray, Mid + 1, High);
        }
    }
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] InputArray = { 10, 5, 6, 8, 23, 19, 12, 17 };
        QuickSortDemo Demo = new QuickSortDemo();
        for (int LoopVariable = 0; LoopVariable < InputArray.Length; LoopVariable++)
        {
            Console.Write(InputArray[LoopVariable]+" ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        Demo.QuickSort(InputArray, 0, InputArray.Length - 1);
        for (int LoopVariable = 0; LoopVariable < InputArray.Length; LoopVariable++)
        {
            Console.Write(InputArray[LoopVariable] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

For some reason I can't get this to work when I take the rightmost element in the array as pivot. I don't know what I am doing wrong. It would be really helpful if someone could explain me why this doesn't work when I take my rightmost element as the pivot. From what I learned, this should work for any input and any pivot element. Correct me if I am wrong. 
Thank you.

Comment: what is the `high` parameter that you pass in the `QuickSort()` function? You pass in `InputArray.Length-1`, shouldn't it be `InputArray[InputArray.Length-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure I understand the question. But I was able to reproduce a problem (infinite recursion) when I change the line of code in the `Partition()` method from `int pivot = inputArray[low];` to `int pivot = inputArray[high];`, and doing so seems consistent with your narrative:

> I can't get this to work when I take the rightmost element in the array as pivot.

If I've understood the question correctly, then the basic problem is that when you change where you get the pivot, you also need to take this into account when returning the new mid-point. Currently, you return `loopVariable2`, which is correct when picking the pivot from the lower end of the array. But if you switch to picking the pivot from the upper end of the array, you need to return `loopVariable2 - 1`.

Another problem is that as you are scanning, you *unconditionally* increment or decrement the respective "loop variable", regardless of whether the current index is already at an element in the wrong partition. You need to check the current element position first, and only adjust the index if that element is in the correct partition.

Here is a correct version of the `Partition()` method where the pivot is selected using `high` instead of `low`:

```
    public int Partition(int[] inputArray, int low, int high)
    {
        int pivot = inputArray[high];
        int loopVariable1 = low;
        int loopVariable2 = high;
        while (true)
        {

            while (inputArray[loopVariable2] > pivot) loopVariable2--;

            while (inputArray[loopVariable1] < pivot) loopVariable1++;


            if (loopVariable1 < loopVariable2)
            {
                Swap(ref inputArray[loopVariable1], ref inputArray[loopVariable2]);
                for (int loopVariable = low; loopVariable <= high; loopVariable++)
                {
                    Console.Write(inputArray[loopVariable] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();

            }
            else
            {
                for (int loopVariable = low; loopVariable <= high; loopVariable++)
                {
                    Console.Write(inputArray[loopVariable] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                return loopVariable2 - 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

In either case, note that the effect is to ensure that regardless of the pivot value selected, you always partition the array in such a way to ensure that a new pivot is always selected with each level of recursion, preventing the infinite loop.

By the way, and for what it's worth, I would not implement `Swap()` as you have. It's an interesting gimmick to do a no-temp-variable swap, but there is no practical benefit to doing so, while it does incur a significant code maintenance and comprehension cost. In addition, it will only work with integral numeric types; what if you want to extend your sort implementation to handle other types? E.g. ones that implement `IComparable` or where you allow the caller to provide an `IComparer` implementation?

IMHO a better `Swap()` method looks like this:

```
    public void Swap<T>(ref T inputA, ref T inputB)
    {
        T temp = inputA;

        inputA = inputB;
        inputB = temp;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I understand what the general idea about returning the pivot element is. But, when I tried to return LoopVariable2-1 as you suggested, the program terminated without entering infinite recursion but the array is not sorted. I copy pasted the partition() method you have put here and tried with my old input set. My teacher said that my original code should work no matter what my pivot it. He even suggested improving it by selecting the pivot randomly at every level. So why doesn't it work when selecting the rightmost element?

Comment: My apologies. For sure, the code you posted doesn't and shouldn't work. But I screwed up in my answer, as I'd forgotten that in the scenario where I'd fixed the code, I'd also changed the way the loop indexes are modified (see my added explanatory paragraph above). Then I promptly posted the wrong version of the code (I'd been playing around with different combinations of the changes to see what their effect was). The above definitely works (and you're right, the previous version did not work on all inputs).

Answer (score 0):

quick sort:

```
   static public int Partition(int [] numbers, int left, int right)
    {
        int pivot = numbers[left];
          while (true)
          {
            while (numbers[left] < pivot)
                left++;

            while (numbers[right] > pivot)
                right--;

            if (left < right)
                {
                int temp = numbers[right];
                numbers[right] = numbers[left];
                numbers[left] = temp;
                }
                else
                {
                      return right;
                }
          }
    }

    static public void QuickSort_Recursive(int [] arr, int left, int right)
    {
        // For Recusrion
        if(left < right)
        {
            int pivot = Partition(arr, left, right);

            if(pivot > 1)
                QuickSort_Recursive(arr, left, pivot - 1);

            if(pivot + 1 < right)
                QuickSort_Recursive(arr, pivot + 1, right);
        }
    }
```